# Cordova NativePageTransitions plugin error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, plugins, transition

I'm trying to use the NativePageTransitions-plugin( http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/native-page-transitions ) for my cordova-project. It works pretty well so far.

Then i read about the feature to manually control the transition, without a fixe delay.

My transition code so far:

```
try {
    var flipOptions = {
        "direction": dir, // 'left|right|up|down', default 'left' (which is like 'next')
        "duration": duration, // in milliseconds (ms), default 400
        "iosdelay": -1, //60, // ms to wait for the iOS webview to update before animation kicks in, default 60
        "androiddelay": -1, //70, // same as above but for Android, default 70
        "winphonedelay": 200 // same as above but for Windows Phone, default 200
    };
    window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.flip(
            flipOptions,
            function (msg) {
                console.log("flip success: " + msg);
            },
            function (msg) {
                console.log("flip error: " + msg);
            }
    );
} catch (e) {
    //alert('error in transition');
    //alert(e.toString());
}
```

and to execute the transition:

```
try {
    window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.executePendingTransition(
            function (msg) {
                alert("manual success: " + msg);
            },
            function (msg) {
                alert("manual error: " + msg);
            }
    );
} catch (e) {
    alert('error in transition execution');
    alert(e.toString());
}
```

Now, when calling the first function, the screen freezes correctly. When calling the second function, i get following outut:

> error in transition
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativepagetransitions' of undefined

What does that mean? How can I resolve this?

Comment: when you receive a TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxxx' of undefined is because you are not waiting for the deviceready event or you didn't link the cordova.js in your index.html

Comment: oh thanks that was actually it... i tried to execute this before the deviceready event was fired. Thanks :)

Comment: Try use $window instead of window